# Odoo 9 customize module with field validation

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am using a new module to customize and existing app. The module installs, and the field appears correctly and saves correctly. The issue is that my custom constraints are ignored.

Here is the full code from my models.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# class myfieldsinsaleorder(models.Model):
#     _name = 'myfieldsinsaleorder.myfieldsinsaleorder'

class partnercustomfields(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    def test(self):
        return False

    x_vend_account_ref = fields.Char(string="Our Account ID",
                                  help='Our account number with this vendor.',
                                  size=20)
    _constraints = [(test,"Invalid Data",[x_vend_account_ref])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mokiSRB for putting me on the right track.  His suggestion of using
@api.constrains is correct but my purposed return value was also wrong.

In looking at other uses of @api.constrains in other modules I find raise UserError. This works, but the method is deprecated. As best as I can gather the correct method to error to raise is ValidationError as this produces the expected result.

```
@api.constrains('x_vend_account_ref')
def customvalidation(self):
    raise ValidationError('The Field Is Not valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraints should be used like this:

`@api.constrains("x_vend_account_ref")
    def test(self):
        return False`

Comment: Unfortunately, even with this change any value is still accepted even after uninstalling the module and re-installing it. Thanks to your suggestion, I went back and checked the docs and tried this as well, but also no luck.     @api.one @api.constrains("x_vend_account_ref")
    def test(self):
        raise ValidationError("Fields name and description must be different")

Comment: Did you restart the server? Every change on model or controller requires restart.

Comment: I have restarted the server. No effect. I've tried several variations, including some attempts which resulted in an exception being thrown which at least confirms the change was applied but I'm still unable to get constraints to function correctly.